# SSAS Tabular Connection Failed with PBIRS when using another user except the PBRIS installation user

Tags: ssas-tabular, power-bi-report-server

I have SSAS tabular and PBIRS on another server and I have some Roles on SSAS with Row level filters, when i tried to develop powerbi report using powerbi desktop, everything is ok but when i uploaded the report to PBIRS, it always gives error when using option (as user view the report).
after reading some articles, i discovered it requires Kerberos integration.
after configuring Kerberos integration, it gives the same error again and even when using option (using the following credentials for data source, it did not accept any user except the installation user of PBIRS).... any recommendation for the solution.

Thank you.

Comment: Any Recommendations dears,

Comment: What does "it did not accept any user except the installation user of PBIRS" mean?  Are you trying to view the report as another user?  If so that requires SSAS admin rights.

Comment: hi David, I gave the user both SSAS server admin privileges' and SSAS DB privileges', however when using this user in PBRIS data source option using the following credentials, it always gives invalid connection string, i dont know why?!, the only working user with this option is PBIRs installation user, and option as user viewing the report is not working!!

Answer (score 0):

If it is failing when testing RLS with "View as...", be aware that PowerBI.com has a bug that RLS is case sensitive when using this feature.
[image]

See https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Service/Is-Role-Level-Security-RLS-Case-Sensitive-for-Email-Addresses/m-p/2504687. I haven't been able to confirm whether access fails, or just when testing with "View as...".

The workaround is to add LOWER( ) to your RLS rule.
`LOWER( [User] ) = LOWER( USERPRINCIPALNAME() )`

I haven't been able to submit a bug report yet.